# What is the difference between "surely" and "definitely" in this context?

Tags: meaning, differences

Here is an FCE Part 1 Practice (Multiple choice):

> There have been countless stories of dolphins appearing to co-operate
> with humans. But a recent incident has convinced a group of lifeguards
> that some dolphins were **definitely** attempting to help them – by
> protecting them from a shark!

Why can **surely** not work in this structure?

Here are the Cambridge Dictionary's definitions:

[surely](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/surely)
[defnitely](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/definitely)

Comment: The links say that surely means *almost certain* (i.e. with small doubt), and definitely means *certain* (i.e. with no doubt). Seems an obvious difference.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth …or then again, I would say no. But the poster cannot judge unless you or I post an answer.

Comment: @David I often reply in 'comments' because I can't find written support for what I have experienced as a practiced Anglophone of over 65 years. Believe me, I'd prefer to give an 'answer', but feel unsupported answers diminish the site. Yet I'd rather give the value of my experience-based perceptions. 'Surely, you cannot be serious!?' employs 'surely' in the pragmatic 'You do agree, don't you!' usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — I disagree, but we've been there before. The real question is whether an MCQ (ugh!) in some English Language exam where the other options are not given — and the poster resorts to dictionary definitions — is suitable for this site. For what it's worth I would say that substitution of "surely" for "definitely" in the sentence gives it a different shade of meaning, more uncertainty if taken as contemporary usage, or 19th century or US regional otherwise. I have as many years experience of the language as you, but the different nature of this results in our different perceptions.

Comment: @David I've just CV-d on 'open to opinion' grounds. Examiners often have different opinions. Though 'definitely' is by far the better answer here on both semantic and pragmatic grounds, 'surely' is not unacceptable. My initial comment, where I say that I consider that 'surely' [almost?] always contains some pragmatic force in the 'getting people onside', cajoling, sense, which isn't really appropriate here, has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

"Surely" can mean "with full success". However, "definitely" tends to mean "without a doubt".

EDIT: I hadn't seen that the words were made links. To further elaborate on my answer, I am going to try to stay within your given example's particular context:

By saying the dolphins were **definitely** attempting to help them, you are saying that there was no doubt whatsoever that the dolphins were there to help. **Surely** could perhaps gives off the same meaning. However, when I put it in the place of **definitely**, I tend to believe that the message is trying to be conveyed as they were successful in their attempt to help the life guards. I could be overreaching here, but think of it this way: If you replace **surely** with the word "successfully"-- which might sound weird-- you get a different meaning. Essentially, by using **definitely**, you are preventing the ambiguity that arises with other meanings of **surely**.

Comment: How is the 1st definition of *surely* from the OP's link different from *without a doubt*? Allex, the system has flagged your post as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. Can I suggest you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g. (1) quote the full definitions, (2) perhaps propose that *surely* has a degree of ambiguity because of its **second** meaning? For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)